# Asymptote on Texmaker not working

Tags: texmaker, asymptote

Title.

This is in a file called `Document.tex`. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{asy}
\dot((0,0));
\end{asy}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The error is `file 'Document-1.pdf' not found`.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: How is `\dot((0,0));` a viable asympote command line? It looks more like a LaTeX command to me. If you remove the backslash, it does become a viable command. After doing that, if I compile your file with `pdflatex`, run `asy Document-1.asy` and then `pdflatex` again, it works.

Comment: No way I made that mistake and didn't catch it before posting LOL my bad. Thanks anyway though @Schrödinger'scat